My mixed poisson regression shows cross-effects between blocks. How do I report this?
I am analyzing salivary biomarker concentrations from pigs in three blocks. The saliva was taken at three sampling points(variable Time), and I have four treatments. My fixed/main effects are treatment and time point. The problem I run into with my model is that descriptively, my blocks show cross effects when block is included as a main effect in the model. That is to say, treatment effects show different trends for each block. When I include interaction effects of treatment and block in my model, my treatment effect is no longer significant, but neither is the treatmentxblock interaction effect. My question is:
Should I chuck up the cross-effects as variation between blocks and just report my significant treatment effect?
Or should I somehow explain the cross-effects and try to interpret them in my results?

